# `Ctrl + C` not working in input() in python when a shared-library is loaded which uses a signal handler

Tags: python, go, operating-system, shared-libraries

`Ctrl + C` not working in input() or getpass() in python when a shared-library is loaded which uses a signal handler.

**Without saving the signal handlers and later restoring them in python, is there a way to fix the issue by just making changes to the go code?**

Repro steps:

1. Go to some directory. Save the `main.go` and `main.py` files (with the content as given below).
2. Run the following command to generate the `.so` file (in linux or Mac).
   `go build -o main.so -buildmode=c-shared main.go`
3. Run `python3 main.py`. If you press Ctrl + C, the go code will get interrupted.
4. However Ctrl+C will not interrupt the input() or getpass() methods. (Ctrl +D or Ctrl+C followed by Enter will do).
5. To fix, save the original handlers before loading the dynamic library, and restore them once call is complete.

We don't see this issue in Windows. We see this issue in both Linux and Mac.

#### `main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "C"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

//export addNums
func addNums(a int, b int) int {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Minute)
    defer cancel()

    // Handle SIGINT (Ctrl+C) and SIGTERM signals
    osSignalChannel := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(osSignalChannel, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    resultCh := make(chan int, 1)

    defer func() {
        signal.Reset(syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
        signal.Stop(osSignalChannel)
        close(osSignalChannel)
        close(resultCh)
    }()

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("Doing a long-running operation")
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Minute)
        resultCh <- a + b
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Context timeout reached")
            return 0
        case returnSignal := <-osSignalChannel:
            fmt.Printf("Interrupted due to signal: %v\n", returnSignal)
            signal.Stop(osSignalChannel)
            signal.Reset(syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
            return 0
        case result := <-resultCh:
            fmt.Println("Long-running operation finished successfully")
            return result
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    // This function is required to build a shared library, but it won't be used.
}
```

#### `main.py`

```py
import ctypes
import getpass
import signal
import time

# Load the shared library
dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./main.so')  # Path to the shared library

# Define the argument and return types of the function
dll.addNums.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]
dll.addNums.restype = ctypes.c_int

# Save the original signal handlers
# original_sigint_handler = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT)
# original_sigterm_handler = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGTERM)

# Call the C function
result = dll.addNums(5, 3)

# Restore the original signal handlers
# signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, original_sigint_handler)
# signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, original_sigterm_handler)

print(f"Result of addNums(5, 3): {result}")
p = input("Press Ctrl + C to exit :) ")
# p = getpass.getpass("Press Ctrl + C to exit :) ")
print(p)
```

Answer (score 2):

Having libraries install their own signal handlers makes this harder to manage. Consider having it expose a handling function, and calling it from Python when trapping.

```py
def handle_signal(signum, stack):
  dll.handleSignal(signum)
  signal.default_int_handler()

# ...

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_signal)
```